# Combine from multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like this:

```
  New_Customer     Order_Id     Invoice
  Aaron            5             5
  John             56            44
  --------------------------  
  Old_Customers    Order_Id     Ticket_Num
  Casey            44            11
  Jonathan          1            4
```

What I want?

```
  All_Customers    All_Order_Ids
  Aaron            5
  John             56
  Casey            44
  Jonathan         1
```

Could I get the union of both of these columns only (without the other columns) with one select statement?

I tried

```
   select tb1.New_Customer union tb2.Old_Customers as All_Customers, tb1.Order_Id union tb2.Order_Id as All_Order_Ids;
```

But I get a error in syntax issue. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I don't quite follow. I am trying to do it in one select satement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform a [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) of 2 select statements with the column aliases presented in the first statement. Those aliases will be picked up and used in the result set.

```
create table t1
(   new_customer varchar(30) not null,
    order_id int not null,
    invoice int not null
);
insert t1 values ('aaron',5,5),('john',56,44);

create table t2
(   old_customers varchar(30) not null,
    order_id int not null,
    ticket_num int not null
);
insert t2 values ('casey',44,11),('jonathan',1,4);
```

### The Query:

```
select new_customer as All_Customers,order_id as All_Order_Ids from t1 
union 
select old_customers,order_id from t2 

+---------------+---------------+
| All_Customers | All_Order_Ids |
+---------------+---------------+
| aaron         |             5 |
| john          |            56 |
| casey         |            44 |
| jonathan      |             1 |
+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: I agree, my first version saying "there ya go bud" deserved a downvote. :>